(ReqNodeNotAvail, UnavailableNodes:localhost) troubleshooting for slurm on a ubuntu standalone laptop
All.
I am new slurm user who wants to install it on my ubuntu laptop just so I can use the qsub command: (https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.7-atpesc2016/tutorials/HandsOnExercise.html , please see the examples lines.)
I installed slurm following this: https://wiki.alcidesfonseca.com/blog/setting-up-slurm-for-single-node-usage-in-ubuntu-2204/ and changed some hostnames and specs in /etc/slurm/gres.conf (attached) following google help.
$ sudo systemctl start slurmctld
$ sinfo --Node --long Mon Sep 16 00:58:46 2024 NODELIST NODES PARTITION STATE CPUS S:C:T MEMORY TMP_DISK WEIGHT AVAIL_FE REASON
localhost 1 LocalQ* unknown* 96 2:24:2 128580 0 1 (null) none
I submitted the jobs using sbatch --wrap "-t 10 -q training -A saumya --mode c16 ./ex2 -ts_max_steps 10 -ts_monitor"
What the queue look like is the following'$ squeue -u saumya JOBID PARTITION NAME USER ST TIME NODES NODELIST(REASON) 1 LocalQ wrap saumya PD 0:00 1 (Nodes required for job are DOWN, DRAINED or reserved for jobs in higher priority partitions) 2 LocalQ wrap saumya PD 0:00 1 (ReqNodeNotAvail, UnavailableNodes:localhost) 3 LocalQ wrap saumya PD 0:00 1 (ReqNodeNotAvail, UnavailableNodes:localhost)
$ journalctl -u slurmctld
attached as journal.txt
$ sudo scontrol update nodename=saumya_TP_GPU state=resume slurm_update error: Invalid node state specified
$ scontrol reconfigure slurm_reconfigure error: Invalid user id
How can I troubleshoot?
Saumya
I tried to troubleshoot from the logs. I cannot tell what the problem is.
Sep 13 07:32:27 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Slurm controller daemon being skipped. Sep 15 04:25:55 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Started Slurm controller daemon. Sep 15 04:25:55 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[201981]: slurmctld: No parameter for mcs plugin, default values set Sep 15 04:25:55 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[201981]: slurmctld: mcs: MCSParameters = (null). ondemand set. Sep 15 04:26:55 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[201981]: slurmctld: SchedulerParameters=default_queue_depth=100,max_rpc_cnt=0,max_sched_time=2,partition_job_depth=0,sched_max_job_start=0,sched_min_interval=2 Sep 15 04:30:55 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[201981]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 04:42:09 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[201981]: slurmctld: Terminate signal (SIGINT or SIGTERM) received Sep 15 04:42:09 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Stopping Slurm controller daemon... Sep 15 04:42:09 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Deactivated successfully. Sep 15 04:42:09 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Stopped Slurm controller daemon. Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Started Slurm controller daemon. Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: Recovered state of 1 nodes Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: Recovered information about 0 jobs Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: part_data_create_array: select/cons_tres: preparing for 1 partitions Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres/gpu: state for localhost Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres_cnt found:TBD configured:2 avail:2 alloc:0 Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres_bit_alloc:NULL Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres_used:(null) Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres/mps: state for localhost Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres_cnt found:TBD configured:200 avail:200 alloc:0 Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres_bit_alloc:NULL Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: gres_used:(null) Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: Recovered state of 0 reservations Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: read_slurm_conf: backup_controller not specified Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: select_p_reconfigure: select/cons_tres: reconfigure Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: part_data_create_array: select/cons_tres: preparing for 1 partitions Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: Running as primary controller Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: No parameter for mcs plugin, default values set Sep 15 04:52:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: mcs: MCSParameters = (null). ondemand set. Sep 15 04:53:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: SchedulerParameters=default_queue_depth=100,max_rpc_cnt=0,max_sched_time=2,partition_job_depth=0,sched_max_job_start=0,sched_min_interval=2 Sep 15 04:55:49 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=1 rc=-1 Sep 15 04:55:49 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=1 rc=0 Sep 15 04:55:49 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: JobId=1 InitPrio=4294901759 usec=607 Sep 15 04:57:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:02:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:07:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:12:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:17:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:22:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:27:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:29:05 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=2 rc=-1 Sep 15 05:29:05 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=2 rc=0 Sep 15 05:29:05 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: JobId=2 InitPrio=4294901758 usec=573 Sep 15 05:30:09 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=3 rc=-1 Sep 15 05:30:09 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=3 rc=0 Sep 15 05:30:09 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: JobId=3 InitPrio=4294901757 usec=795 Sep 15 05:32:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:37:08 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:37:33 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: Terminate signal (SIGINT or SIGTERM) received Sep 15 05:37:33 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Stopping Slurm controller daemon... Sep 15 05:37:33 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[205109]: slurmctld: Saving all slurm state Sep 15 05:37:33 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Deactivated successfully. Sep 15 05:37:33 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Stopped Slurm controller daemon. Sep 15 05:37:33 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Consumed 1.649s CPU time. Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU systemd[1]: Started Slurm controller daemon. Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: Recovered state of 1 nodes Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: Recovered JobId=1 Assoc=0 Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: Recovered JobId=2 Assoc=0 Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: Recovered JobId=3 Assoc=0 Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: Recovered information about 3 jobs Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: part_data_create_array: select/cons_tres: preparing for 1 partitions Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres/gpu: state for localhost Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres_cnt found:TBD configured:2 avail:2 alloc:0 Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres_bit_alloc:NULL Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres_used:(null) Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres/mps: state for localhost Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres_cnt found:TBD configured:200 avail:200 alloc:0 Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres_bit_alloc:NULL Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: gres_used:(null) Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: Recovered state of 0 reservations Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: read_slurm_conf: backup_controller not specified Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: select_p_reconfigure: select/cons_tres: reconfigure Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: part_data_create_array: select/cons_tres: preparing for 1 partitions Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: Running as primary controller Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: No parameter for mcs plugin, default values set Sep 15 05:40:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: mcs: MCSParameters = (null). ondemand set. Sep 15 05:40:47 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=4 rc=-1 Sep 15 05:40:47 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: select/cons_tres: common_job_test: no job_resources info for JobId=4 rc=0 Sep 15 05:40:47 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: JobId=4 InitPrio=4294901756 usec=733 Sep 15 05:40:48 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: SchedulerParameters=default_queue_depth=100,max_rpc_cnt=0,max_sched_time=2,partition_job_depth=0,sched_max_job_start=0,sched_min_interval=2 Sep 15 05:45:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:50:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 05:55:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding Sep 15 06:00:23 saumya-TP-GPU slurmctld[208095]: slurmctld: error: Nodes localhost not responding
